# How to add required to input field and change the message error when it's empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm working with jQuery validation, libelle_length==0 doesn't work and I want to change the error message to "please fill in this field" when it's empty

jQuery :

```
$(function() {
        $("#libelle_error_message").hide();
        $("#montant_error_message").hide();

        var error_libelle = false;
        var error_montant = false;

        $("#libelle").focusout(function() {
            var libelle_length = $("#libelle").val().length;

        //libelle should be required and I want to change the message when the field is empty
            if((libelle_length < 4 )|| (libelle_length==0)) {
                $("#libelle_error_message").html("Erreur : Libellé doit contenir au moins 4 caractère");
                $("#libelle_error_message").show();
                error_libelle = true;
            } else {
                $("#libelle_error_message").hide();
            }
        });
}
```

My form :

```
<form class="forms-sample" action="depense" method="POST" id="FormDepense"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<label for="libelle">libelle</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="libelle" name="libelle" placeholder="libelle" >
<span class="error_form" id="libelle_error_message"></span></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you've tried so far as I don't see where this fits in the validator, but I think I can help you.

To override the messages, try adding something similar to the below in a separate file or script *after* the jQuery validation plugin.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than {0}.")
    required: "please fill in this field.",
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I just want to make a test on libelle.length !== "" and display the message as above, but  it doesn't work

Comment: Are you using the jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: yes, and i'm following this example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaRZEdYRfaU

Comment: Ah!  I see.  I don't want to ever discourage someone from writing the low level / homegrown code... but I think there is an easier way to do this.  You might want to take a look at the official jquery validator plugin @ https://jqueryvalidation.org/   - it may save you a lot of headache :)

Comment: Great ! Thank you